# How to drag multiple menu items at once in WordPress?

Tags: menus, sub-menu

Say, I added 8 items to a menu. Now I want to bring all the 8 items under another item. Dragging them one by one can take ages. How do I drag them all at once?

Comment: Also please follow this feature request ticket on Wordpress.org:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31906#comment:7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution :

First, make all of your pages you want to move to be a subitem of some other item(the best way is creating one for this action bacuse you will delete parent item).

[image]

[image]

Remeber that when you move your items you must move it with parent item like above.
Then put items in place you choosen and delete parent item . Here - "Stowarzyszenie" . I hope that language won't be any problem :) All done!

If you want to place moven items as a submenu then parent item must be on the level you choosen:

[image]

Comment: Now why didn't I think of this?! If there are no 'press Ctrl and drag' options in WordPress, then this is the way to do it.

Comment: An alternative way of managing your pages and navigation menu might be with the [Nested Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-nested-pages/) plugin